# WD My Passport is not detected by machine

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

When I plug in my WD My Passport, I can't see it in File Explorer. However, I do see it in "Device Manager" under "Disk Drives".

I tried updating the driver, etc., which didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Go to Start, type in `compmgmt.msc`, and press enter. Then go to "Disk Management" under Storage.  Do you see your drive there?

Comment: no, it isn't there..tried to update firmware (was successful but still drive isn't detected..)

Comment: mm wait I see 1T unallocated...

Comment: wierd, I gave it a letter, he forced me to format (I did) and now it is available as another drive...ok so it seems to work in some weird level..thanks you very much for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your disk has no partition on it ? Go to disk manager in computer manager and check your disk contents.